# How to get the buffer size required by NtQueryInformationProcess?

Tags: windows, delphi

The ReturnLength parameter of NtQueryInformationProcess is documented as follows:

> **ReturnLength**
>
> A pointer to a variable in which the function returns the size of the requested information. If the function was successful, this is the size of the information written to the buffer pointed to by the ProcessInformation parameter, but if the buffer was too small, this is the minimum size of buffer needed to receive the information successfully.

the part that is of particular interest is: **if the buffer was too small, this is the minimum size of buffer needed to receive the information successfully.**

I wanted the function to return the buffer size required for a specific information class.

I tried the following:

```
 // for static linking

function NtQueryInformationProcess(ProcessHandle        : THANDLE;
                               ProcessInformationClass  : DWORD;
                               ProcessInformation       : PPEB;
                               ProcessInformationLength : DWORD;
                               ReturnLength             : PDWORD)
     : NTSTATUS; stdcall; external ntdll;

 // for dynamic linking

 type
   TNtQueryInformationProcess
     = function (ProcessHandle       : THANDLE;
            ProcessInformationClass  : DWORD;
            ProcessInformation       : PPEB;
            ProcessInformationLength : DWORD;
            ReturnLength             : PDWORD) : NTSTATUS; stdcall;

var
  ProcessHandle : THANDLE;

  Peb           : TPEB;
  BufferSize    : DWORD;
  ReturnLength  : DWORD;
  NtResult      : NTSTATUS;
  NtdllHandle   : HMODULE;
  NtQueryInformationProcessPtr : TNtQueryInformationProcess;

begin
 ProcessHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,
                              FALSE,
                              GetCurrentProcessId());

 ZeroMemory(@Peb, sizeof(Peb));
 BufferSize   := sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION);
 ReturnLength := 0;

 NtResult := NtQueryInformationProcess(ProcessHandle,
                                       ProcessBasicInformation,
                                    @Peb,
                                    BufferSize,
                                   @ReturnLength);

 writeln('NTSTATUS     : ', IntToHex(NtResult, 0));
 writeln('ReturnLength : ', ReturnLength);

 // try calling the function by address

 NtdllHandle := LoadLibrary('ntdll.dll');

 pointer(NtQueryInformationProcessPtr) := GetProcAddress(NtdllHandle,
                                             'NtQueryInformationProcess');

 // reinitialize just to be safe

 ZeroMemory(@Peb, sizeof(Peb));
 BufferSize   := sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION);
 ReturnLength := 0;

 NtResult := NtQueryInformationProcessPtr(ProcessHandle,
                                          ProcessBasicInformation,
                                       @Peb,
                                       BufferSize,
                                       @ReturnLength);

 writeln('NTSTATUS     : ', IntToHex(NtResult, 0));
 writeln('ReturnLength : ', ReturnLength);

 writeln('program end.');
 readln;
end.
```

when I set the size of the buffer to the correct size for ProcessBasicInformation everything works as expected but, if I set the BufferSize to zero (for instance) wanting the function to return the necessary buffer size in the ReturnLength variable, I get a return of 0xC0000004 (size mismatch) which is as expected BUT, the ReturnLength variable is not set to the size required to successfully get the ProcessBasicInformation.

Given the description of the ReturnLength parameter, I expected the API to set ReturnLength to whatever size the information class requested requires.

**My question is:** is there a mistake in the code or does the API not work as documented ? or am I misinterpreting the description of the ReturnLength parameter ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Usually with APIs like this you have to set both the buffer size to 0 and pass in NULL as the buffer pointer. In order to receive the required length back

Comment: @Nick: actually, most of the time one of both will do: either buffer size 0 or buffer nil or of course both.

Comment: The pattern is usually the same: you pass a buffer size that is too small, and the function will return an error and tell you the required size. The value 0 for buffer size is certainly too small, so that is the best value to pass. It can't hurt to pass nil for th buffer either. This also tells the function you don't know the buffer size. Most functions will react to both: buffersize too small, or buffer nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many Win32 API's are designed to tell you the correct buffer size by calling it with a nil pointer and specify 0 for ReturnLength. The Nt api's usually work a bit differently:

You just pass it a buffer of an arbitrary size and it will tell you if it wants more by returning `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH`.

I also recommend to use the [Jedi Api Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/) rather than translating the (Nt Api) functions/headers yourself.

**EDIT**: Seems like you are trying to read the ProcessBasicInformation class which has a fixed size and doesn't return a pointer to the PEB but a pointer to a `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION` struct/record.

Here is an example for what you are trying to do:

```
// uses JwaNative

function TDebugThread.ReadPEB: Boolean;
var
  nts: NTSTATUS;
  pbi: PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION;
  dwBytes: DWORD;
begin
  Result := False;
  nts := NtQueryInformationProcess(pi.hProcess,
    ProcessBasicInformation, @pbi, SizeOf(pbi), @dwBytes);

  if nts <> STATUS_SUCCESS then
    Exit;

  New(PEB);
  Result := ReadProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, pbi.PebBaseAddress, PEB, SizeOf(PEB^),
    @dwBytes);

end;
```

Below an example using `NtQuerySystemInformation` (full example can be found on my GitHub [repository](https://github.com/rweijnen/ProcessUnit)).

```
{ TProcessList }
constructor TProcessList.Create(const AOwnsObjects: Boolean = True);
var
  Current: PSystemProcesses;
  SystemProcesses : PSystemProcesses;
  dwSize: DWORD;
  nts: NTSTATUS;
begin
  inherited Create(AOwnsObjects);

  dwSize := 200000;
  SystemProcesses := AllocMem(dwSize);

  nts := NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessesAndThreadsInformation,
      SystemProcesses, dwSize, @dwSize);

  while nts = STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH do
  begin
    ReAllocMem(SystemProcesses, dwSize);
    nts := NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessesAndThreadsInformation,
      SystemProcesses, dwSize, @dwSize);
  end;

  if nts = STATUS_SUCCESS then
  begin
    Current := SystemProcesses;
    while True do
    begin
      Self.Add(TProcess.Create(Current^));
      if Current^.NextEntryDelta = 0 then
        Break;

      Current := PSYSTEM_PROCESSES(DWORD_PTR(Current) + Current^.NextEntryDelta);
    end;
  end;

  FreeMem(SystemProcesses);
end;
```

**Edit**: to answer @ScienceAmateur comment the following test code always returns 0 for ReturnLength:

```
uses
  Windows,
  System.SysUtils,
  Rtti,
  JwaNative,
  JwaWinType,
  JwaNtSecApi,
  JwaNtStatus;


function NtStatusErrorMessage(const nts: NTSTATUS): String;
begin
  Result := SysErrorMessage(LsaNtStatusToWinError(nts));
end;

var
  nts: NTSTATUS;
  pic: PROCESS_INFORMATION_CLASS;
  Buffer: Pointer;
  pil: DWORD;
  ReturnLength: DWORD;
begin
  for pic := Low(PROCESS_INFORMATION_CLASS) to High(PROCESS_INFORMATION_CLASS) do
  begin
    Buffer := nil;
    pil := 0;
    ReturnLength := 0;
    nts := NtQueryInformationProcess(GetCurrentProcess,
      ProcessBasicInformation, Buffer, pil, @ReturnLength);
    WriteLn(Format('%s: returned 0x%.8x and ReturnLength: %d', [TRttiEnumerationType.GetName(pic), nts, ReturnLength]));
  end;

  WriteLn('Finished.');

  if DebugHook <> 0 then
    ReadLn;
```

Output:

```
ProcessBasicInformation: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessQuotaLimits: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessIoCounters: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessVmCounters: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessTimes: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessBasePriority: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessRaisePriority: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessDebugPort: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessExceptionPort: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessAccessToken: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessLdtInformation: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessLdtSize: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessDefaultHardErrorMode: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessIoPortHandlers: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessPooledUsageAndLimits: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessWorkingSetWatch: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessUserModeIOPL: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessEnableAlignmentFaultFixup: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessPriorityClass: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessWx86Information: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessHandleCount: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessAffinityMask: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessPriorityBoost: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessDeviceMap: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessSessionInformation: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessForegroundInformation: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessWow64Information: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessImageFileName: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessLUIDDeviceMapsEnabled: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessBreakOnTermination: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessDebugObjectHandle: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessDebugFlags: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
ProcessHandleTracing: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
MaxProcessInfoClass: returned 0xC0000004 and ReturnLength: 0
```

Comment: In what way are the Nt APIs different (in this respect)? Most APIs will return an error and give you the correct size (either as return value or in a reference/pointer parameter) *if the buffer is too small*. Of course 0 is certainly too small, so you can always pass 0.

Comment: Should have probably explained it more clearly @RudyVelthuis it depends a little bit on the information class that is used. See my edit.

Comment: Ok, that **is** different. <g>

Comment: why you call `NtQuerySystemInformation` 2 time (from 2 place) in src code, when possible do this only once from do ; while loop

Comment: @RbMm The first call will succeed and return STATUS_SUCCESS if the buffer is large enough (which it usually is). Only if the buffer is not large enough it will be called a 2nd time (if the return value is STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH).

Comment: but possible have only single call inside do ; while loop. not need second call from src code. like `do
status = NtQuerySystemInformation(..)
while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)`

Comment: also use `ReAllocMem` here bad choice. the realloc usually slow compare alloc because it  preserve the content of the memory being reallocated, even if the new memory is allocated at a different location ( involves a memory copy operation ). but we not need preserve the content of the memory here

Comment: Since the initial buffer is very large you probably will never hit then 2nd call nor the ReAllocMem but feel free to rewrite this as you please ;-)

Comment: @Remko are you saying that for ProcessBasicInformation, ReturnLength is not set to the required buffer size but, is set to the required buffer size for other process information classes ?  if that is what you are saying and, it is true/correct then the documented description of ReturnLength in MSDN is "questionable" since no exceptions are noted in it.

Comment: @ScienceAmateur yes `NtQueryInformationProcess` always seems to return the actual ReturnLength rather than desired (which will be 0 in that case).

Comment: @Remko, thank you.  I appreciate the efforts you put into clarifying the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with this function. The issue is that the size depends on the bitness, because you need to provide the size of a pointer.

These are the paramenter of the function :

```
NTSTATUS(WINAPI*)(
    _In_ HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    _In_ PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
    _Out_ PVOID ProcessInformation,
    _In_ ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
    _Out_opt_ PULONG ReturnLength);
```

The NtQueryInformationProcess function can be called with several different PROCESSINFOCLASS. This then determines what type the ProcessInformation will be.
It can point to a DWORD, if for example you call it with `ProcessDebugPort` or a `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION` if you call it with `ProcessBasicInformation`.

If when you call the function you provide `sizeof(DWORD)` then in 32bit your app would work. But in 64bit it wouldn't.

This is because in 32bit DWORD, which is a `unsigned long`, has the same size as `unsigned long ptr`, but in 64bit the pointer is 64bit.

So the size that you really need in this case is the size of the pointer and not the type, nor the variable which you reference in the call.

Basically this works everywhere :

```
DWORD debuggerPortNumber = 0;
NTSTATUS status = NtQueryInformationProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), ProcessDebugPort, &debuggerPortNumber, sizeof(PDWORD), nullptr);
```

And this will break for 64bit application :

```
DWORD debuggerPortNumber = 0;
NTSTATUS status = NtQueryInformationProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), ProcessDebugPort, &debuggerPortNumber, sizeof(DWORD), nullptr);
```